# Date selection comparison with Date_Time data column using Linq query in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I need my Linq query to compare Date_Time (has only date in data not date_time, datatype - nvarchar) column with date selection of Date1.Value (string) but without showing any error my Gridview doesn't get populated. If I remove the Date_Time where condition, the page runs well. I would be really thankful if someone could help me out with this.

Regards,

Tejas

[image: This image displays Date_Time data format in SQL]

[image: Image shows the Date selection option on the web portal]

```
private void populateData()
    {
        // here code for populate data
        using (TrialEntities13 dc = new TrialEntities13())
        {
            var v = (from p in dc.Vehicle_Andon
                     where (p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue
                      && p.Loss_Type == 9 && p.Date_Time == Date1.Value)
                     join s in dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER on p.Loss_Description equals s.Loss_Description
                     select new
                     {
                         p,
                         s.Loss_Description,
                     });
            List<Vehicle_Andon> allP = new List<Vehicle_Andon>();

            foreach (var i in v)
            {
                Vehicle_Andon p = new Vehicle_Andon();
                p = i.p;
                p.Loss_Description = i.Loss_Description;
                
                allP.Add(p);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = allP;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"datatype - nvarchar"* That's your first problem - dates should **never** be stored as strings. Change your column type to `date`.

Comment: First I had stored it in Date format itself but since the Date1 I select is in string format, I changed the data type to nvarchar for date-time column

Comment: Don't. Never stores dates as strings!